# Internal Exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

So my friends have a server, and I was trying to join the server, but every time I try, I would be able to connect and see the terrain load around me, but after a while, the server would just kick me off and show the error message: Internal Exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer. So I'm just wondering if anyone knows a way to fix this problem

Comment: My internet doesn't disconnect.

Comment: Okay, but did you try the answers given there? That the symptoms aren't alike doesn't mean the solution can't be.